# Android: media player play from url :Failed to open file error

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I am trying to implement a simple media player in android that contains  only two buttons one for play another for pause

**Play**

```
  String url = " http://host/audio/01_-_Pat.mp3";
 public void onClick(View v) {
                 try{

                     mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                     mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(MainActivity.this);
                     mPlayer.prepareAsync();

                 }catch (Exception e)
                 {
                     Log.v("Error", String.valueOf(e));
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
                 mPlayer.start();
             }
```

I didn't get any exception on this code but i will get this error
 *

> Failed to open file ' http://host.com/audio/01_-_Pat.mp3'. (No such
>   file or directory)

*
Actually the url is valid and it contains the audio

Comment: are you having access for that audio file..?

Comment: Yes i have an access for that

Comment: also check if your url returning a .mp3 file,there may a chance that the url returning html page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your code:
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

```
 String url = " http://host/audio/01_-_Pat.mp3";
 public void onClick(View v) {
                 try{
                     mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                     mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                     mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(MainActivity.this);
                     mPlayer.prepareAsync();

                 }catch (Exception e)
                 {
                     Log.v("Error", String.valueOf(e));
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
                 mPlayer.start();
             }
```

Comment: When I use the uri after its working but in devices greater than 5 will return the same error ie file not found